# Why Do I get Odoo Server Error after creating XML files

Tags: python, odoo, erp

I get an error, so after adding my `views/xml` and enabling the super user to access the `custom module`. I get an error of

> `RPC_ERROR Odoo Server Error`

I tried creating new database and account, change my odoo.conf

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo16v1
db_password = odoo16v1
addons_path = server/addons , server/customaddons , C:/Odoo/odoo16/server/customaddons
default_productivity_apps = True
http_port = 8050
```

But what happens is when I install the new app to my new database, and refresh the app, I get `cancel install` instead,

```
RPC_ERROR
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\api.py", line 984, in get
    cache_value = field_cache[record._ids[0]]
KeyError: 335

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1160, in __get__
    value = env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\api.py", line 991, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'ir.actions.act_window(335,).search_view'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\http.py", line 1584, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 133, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\http.py", line 1611, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\http.py", line 1815, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 154, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\http.py", line 697, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\action.py", line 34, in load
    action = request.env[action_type].sudo().browse([action_id]).read()
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions.py", line 272, in read
    result = super(IrActionsActWindow, self).read(fields, load=load)
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\models.py", line 2986, in read
    return self._read_format(fnames=fields, load=load)
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\models.py", line 3165, in _read_format
    vals[name] = convert(record[name], record, use_name_get)
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\models.py", line 5898, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1209, in __get__
    self.compute_value(recs)
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1387, in compute_value
    records._compute_field_value(self)
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\models.py", line 4222, in _compute_field_value
    fields.determine(field.compute, self)
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\fields.py", line 97, in determine
    return needle(*args)
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_actions.py", line 240, in _compute_search_view
    fvg = self.env[act.res_model].get_view(act.search_view_id.id, 'search')
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\api.py", line 537, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name](self, (), ())
  File "C:\Odoo\odoo16\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 190, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'hospital.patient'

The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    at makeErrorFromResponse (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/121-df8555b/web.assets_backend.min.js:992:163)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/121-df8555b/web.assets_backend.min.js:1000:13)
```

What I did:

I tried changing database account and reinstall again but when i tried to search the app i get `cancel install`.

oom_hospital/**manifest**.py

```
{
    'name': 'Hospital Management V1',
    'author': 'odoodev16v1',
    'data': [
        'views/menu.xml',
        'views/patient_view.xml'
    ]
}
```

oom_hospital/views/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

    <menuitem
            id="menu_hospital_root"
            name="Hospital"
            sequence="0"
    />

    <menuitem
            id="menu_patient_master"
            name="Patient Details"
            parent="menu_hospital_root"
            sequence="0"
    />
</odoo>
```

oom_hospital/views/patient_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="action_hospital_patient" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Patients</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">hospital.patient</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="context">{}</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="no_view_nocontent_smilling_face">
                Create your first patient
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>

    <menuitem
            id="menu_patient"
            name="Patient"
            action="action_hospital_patient"
            parent="menu_patient_master"
            sequence="0"
    />

</odoo>
```

Comment: The errors says that the model `hospital.patient` is missing. Did you do something wrong on that part?

Comment: no, I didn't do anything yet, i just tried to upgrade it after adding the `xml`